# How extend Illuminate\Routing\Router class in Laravel 10?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to extend class `Illuminate\Routing\Router` to be able to modify the `toResponse` method. So far this is what I have done:

I have created a class called `Router` that extends class `Illuminate\Routing\Router`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;

class Router extends BaseRouter
{
    /**
     * Static version of prepareResponse.
     *
     * @param $request
     * @param $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public static function toResponse($request, $response)
    {
        if ($response instanceof HttpResponse) {
            return 'Hello instance of HttpResponse';
        }

        return parent::toResponse($request, $response);
    }
}
```

I have created a service provider named `RoutingServiceProvider` with the following structure:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RoutingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->extend('router', function (Router $router, Application $app) {
            return new \App\Http\Responses\Router($app['events'], $app);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, I have registered the service provider inside the `Kernel` file, as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use App\Providers\RoutingServiceProvider;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
     ....
    public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
    {
        $app->register(new RoutingServiceProvider($app));

        parent::__construct($app, $router);
    }
```

The router instance inside the container is being modified to the class I created, but unfortunately when I try to get the `'router'` instance from the container, it is returning my class without the application routes. In fact all the properties of the class are empty.

When I do:
 `dd(resolve('router'))`

I get the following:

```
App\Http\Responses\Router^ {#239 // app/Http/Kernel.php:98
  #events: Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher^ {#26 …5}
  #container: Illuminate\Foundation\Application^ {#3 …40}
  #routes: Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection^ {#240
    #routes: []
    #allRoutes: []
    #nameList: []
    #actionList: []
  }
  #current: null
  #currentRequest: null
  #middleware: []
  #middlewareGroups: []
  +middlewarePriority: []
  #binders: []
  #patterns: []
  #groupStack: []
}
```

I would appreciate in advance any help or experience from someone who has tried to do something similar. Thank you so much.